# HashMap with Boolean inside get reset when onchange in tabview is call

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have one Hashmap inside a tabview with two tab on the first tab the user can see all object he selected on the second he can see all object he can select. it's the same Hashmap for both.

**XHTML:**

```
<p:tabView id="tabViewElement" style="margin-top: 5px;min-height: 50px;max-height: 300px;overflow-x: hidden;" dynamic="true" activeIndex="0">
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{Bean.onTabChangeElement}" update="tabViewElement:productConfs tabViewElement:cardsElements" />
<p:tab id="idTabElementView" title="Elements Sectionnes">
    <h:inputText rendered="#{Bean.objectselected}" value="Aucun produit selectionné"/>
    <p:dataTable id="productConfs" var="productConf" value="#{Bean.keyAsListForAllElement}" rendered="#{Bean.objectselected}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="ELEMENTS" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="" rendered="#{Bean.listAllElement[productConf]}">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{Bean.listAllElement[productConf]}">
                <p:ajax listener="#{Bean.checkBoxElement}" update="productConfs" />
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Reference" rendered="#{Bean.listAllElement[productConf]}">
            <h:outputText value="#{productConf.reference}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Indice majeur" rendered="#{Bean.listAllElement[productConf]}">
            <h:outputText value="#{productConf.majorIndex}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Indice mineur" rendered="#{Bean.listAllElement[productConf]}">
            <h:outputText value="#{productConf.minorIndex}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Designation" rendered="#{Bean.listAllElement[productConf]}">
            <h:outputText value="#{productConf.productConfModel.reference}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Identifiable" rendered="#{Bean.listAllElement[productConf]}">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="true" value="#{productConf.identifiable}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:tab>
<p:tab id="tabSelectedElement" title="Choisir Elements" style="margin-top: 5px;max-height:400px;overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: hidden;">
    <p:dataTable id="cardsElements" var="cardElement" value="#{Bean.keyAsListForAllElement}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="ELEMENTS" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{Bean.listAllElement[cardElement]}">
                <p:ajax listener="#{Bean.checkBoxElement}" update="cardsElements" />
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Reference">
            <h:outputText value="#{cardElement.reference}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Indice majeur">
            <h:outputText value="#{cardElement.majorIndex}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Indice mineur">
            <h:outputText value="#{cardElement.minorIndex}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Designation">
            <h:outputText value="#{cardElement.productConfModel.reference}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Identifiable">
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox disabled="true" value="#{cardElement.identifiable}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

The second tab works well when i check or not one object i can see him on the first, but when i uncheck one from the first tab i see him disappear but when i switch to the second tab he reappear.

I have put this on my code for check how many object as for value true in my HashMap.

**BEAN**

```
private HashMap<Product, Boolean> listAllElement = new HashMap<Product, Boolean>();

public void onTabChangeElement(TabChangeEvent event) {
    System.out.println("TAB CHANGE");
}

public List<Product> getKeyAsListForAllElement() {
    int i = 0;
    for (Entry<Product, Boolean> e : this.listAllElement.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue() == true) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("BOOLEAN TRUE = " + i);
    return new ArrayList<Product>(this.listAllElement.keySet());
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
BOOLEAN TRUE = 1
BOOLEAN TRUE = 1
BOOLEAN TRUE = 1
BOOLEAN TRUE = 1
BOOLEAN TRUE = 2
TAB CHANGE
BOOLEAN TRUE = 2
BOOLEAN TRUE = 2
BOOLEAN TRUE = 2
BOOLEAN TRUE = 2
```

I work on primefaces 3.5 with Tomcat 7.

Can anybody help me out here, where is the problem?

Comment: What's the scope of your bean?

Comment: So what output are you expecting? On which tab are you starting when it produces the given output?

Comment: I expect the number of true in hashmap value doesn't change when i switching between tab.

Cause in one way this works but not in the other and it's the same code.

Comment: What's your `checkBoxElement` method doing? It looks like the values are changing in server side. Why don't you check it using a debugger instead of system out prints? Just see when the values are being overwritten.

Comment: The Method display a message inside p:growl. 

The value just get overwritten when event="tabChange" is call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fix my problem. I have to delete this listener:

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{Bean.onTabChangeElement}" update="tabViewElement:productConfs tabViewElement:cardsElements" />
```

And add another coponent to update inside p:selectBooleanCheckbox listener.

```
<p:ajax listener="#{ConfigurationProductBean.checkBoxElement}" update="cardsElements :form:tabViewElement:productConfs" />
```

That work fine ! Thank you for your help !